# Own String parser java which solves mathematical equations wrote down in a string

Tags: java, string, parsing, math, substring

I've wrote a method/function in Java which returns the result of a given basic equation. This equation will be given as a String and I think I got this method working but don't know why I need this one line of Code because this should work without it. After trying for more than an hour to solve it I gave up and hope you can give me an aswer.

Here the Code:

```
    public static double format(String s) {

    char[] c = s.toCharArray();

    if(s.contains("(")) {
        int openbrackets = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 2; i++) {
            if (c[i] == '(') openbrackets++;
            else if (c[i] == ')') {
                openbrackets--;
                if(openbrackets == 0) {
                    s = s.replace(s.substring(s.indexOf('('), i+1), ""+(format(s.substring(s.indexOf('(')+1, i))));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (s.contains("(")) {    // String can still contains brackets
        s = "" + format(s);
    }

    c = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = c.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(c[i] == '+') {
            return format(s.substring(0, i)) + format(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
        } else if(c[i] == '-') {
            return format(s.substring(0, i)) - format(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
        }
    }

    for(int i = s.length()-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if(c[i] == '*') {
            return format(s.substring(0, i)) * Double.parseDouble(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
        } else if (c[i] == '/') {
            return format(s.substring(0, i)) / Double.parseDouble(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
        }
    }

    return s.equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(s); // I don't understand why I need to do this line
}
```

**Description:**
I don't know why I need this s.equals("") ? : because the String never should be empty however when I run it with this equation ((23)+(23-23-432-35-1-2-4231+2312+12323-(-3))*3/2) for example I get an error without it.
I need the parser to convert config Strings into Numbers for example when it comes to screenresolution. I know I can also use Libraries but I want to try these things by myself.

PS: Dont hate me just because I don't use libraries. I really tried to figure it out and I have fun doing it. I would just like to know why I have to write this little Codeline as I don't figure it out...

Edit: Error was a NumberFormatException as the Parsing got an empty String... Got my error now also the OverflowException which was mentioned in the comments...

EDIT: To everyone who MIGHT use something like this in the future:
Here the Code which actually works:

```
    public static double format(String s) {
    s = s.replace(" ", "");
    s = s.replace("\t", "");
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    if(s.contains("(")) {
        int openbrackets = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (c[i] == '(') openbrackets++;
            else if (c[i] == ')') {
                openbrackets--;
                if(openbrackets == 0) {
                    s = s.replace(s.substring(s.indexOf('('), i+1), ""+(format(s.substring(s.indexOf('(')+1, i))));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (s.contains("(")) s = "" + format(s);
    c = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = c.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if(c[i] == '+') {
            return format(s.substring(0, i)) + format(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
        } else if(c[i] == '-') {
            return format(s.substring(0, i)) - format(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
        }
    }
    for(int i = s.length()-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if(c[i] == '*') {
            return format(s.substring(0, i)) * Double.parseDouble(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
        } else if (c[i] == '/') {
            return format(s.substring(0, i)) / Double.parseDouble(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
        }
    }
    return s.equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think we would hate you because you don't use libraries? We do hate you a little bit for not including the error in your question though.

Comment: You say **I get an error without it** - what error? It's hard to know what's wrong if you don't give us the exact error as reported. Please add it to the question.

Comment: Also, because you're calling your function recursively, I'm guessing that eventually you're calling it with an empty string as the `s` argument. Have you actually tried **debugging** your code? That should be the first thing you do.

Comment: You should consider using a debugger...

Comment: Throw it all away and look up recursive descent expression parsing, or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Comment: You should say what string causes an error (and what error) without this line. Anyway, I suspect that there are other problems here, because `"2*(6-4)"` ends in a StackOverflow error, with or without the line...

Comment: The error I had was a NumberFormatException. Sry forgot to include this... This is my first post you know ;)
It was thrown by an empty string which refers to the last line in the method where I say Double.parseDouble(s);

Comment: Apart from this I fixed the bug that there is a StackOverflowException... I totally messed up the things in my head.
In line 7 you just need to delete -2 after the s.lenght()
Thought I would refer there to "(" but instead refered to ")"...

Comment: You should add the error stuff to an edit of the question. Comments should be supplemental to the question, not contain part of their specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is at least one location in your code where you pass a 0 length string to your `format` function:

```
c = s.toCharArray();
for(int i = c.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(c[i] == '+') {
        return format(s.substring(0, i)) + format(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
    } else if(c[i] == '-') {
        return format(s.substring(0, i)) - format(s.substring(i+1, s.length()));
    }
}
```

Your loop counter in `(int i = c.length-1; i >= 0; i--)` will get decremented until it is `0` in value if there are no `+` or `-` values in the input string.
Then you call `format(s.substring(0, i))` where `i = 0` so I think this is one place where you will be passing a zero length/empty string to your `function`.

Please use a debugger and step through your code - not only would it teach you a valuable skill it would also probably give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the Debugger ;)
Actually I used some System.out.println();s to see what the program is doing... Also I wrote a little Logger which told me the error refers to the last line and to the part you told me but I did not see why the program did so... Thx though :)